# Confusion about memory positions

Tags: assembly, struct, cpu-architecture

I've been reading a book related to computer architecture and i got stuck in a particular situation, take a look:

In a computer, the word and bus size is **32 bits**. Suppose you want to store **3 variables in memory**:

> a)First name initial (8 bits, char)
>
> b)First last initial (8 bits,char)
>
> c)ID number (32 bits, int)

Two ways of storage were proposed:

[image]

I got this question rolling in my mind:

Why 'Way B' occupies fewer memory locations than 'Way A' when they both contain the same variables?. Which of the two ways of storing the variables is more efficient when they are accessed in memory?

Can somebody please explain that to me?

Comment: I think the adresses should be 0x0000 and 0x0004. You can check this link.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/

Comment: In 'Way B' there is one memory access (read) for word at address '0000'. Then in order to get 'last name' and 'first name' you would simply use bitwise operation which are very efficient.

Comment: You should probably want to mark the grey sign under any of the answers, if your problem is resolved.

Comment: Hey buddy, how are you?
I'm reading everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum addressable unit is 32-bit, it somewhat weird, but not a problem.

Let's take a look at how `FIRST NAME` and `LAST NAME` is stored in Way A

```
 31                                         7           0
+------------------------------------------+------------+
|                  UNUSED                  | FIRST NAME |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
|                  UNUSED                  | LAST NAME  |
+------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Only the least significant 8 bits are used, higher 24 bits are not used. If we want to save space, it's obvious that we can put at most 24 bits of information in the unused area. That's what Way B does.

```
 31                            15           7           0
+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|            UNUSED           | LAST NAME  | FIRST NAME |
+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Way B puts both `FIRST NAME` and `LAST NAME` in the same unit on memory, with less unused space. So way B is more space efficient.

When it comes to access efficiency, that's another story. In Way A, we can access all three members with their own addresses.

```
FIRST NAME : 0000
ID         : 0001
LAST NAME  : 0002
```

its equivalent C code is:

```
struct S {
    char first_name;
    int id;
    char last_name;
};
```

But in Way B, `FIRST NAME` and `LAST NAME` shares the same address, we need to use bit manipulation to get them.

```
FIRST NAME : 0000 (bit 0~7)
LAST NAME  : 0000 (bit 8~15)
ID         : 0001
```

Its equivalent C code can be (here I am not going to use bit field). Since there is no direct way to access these two members, we need the following operation:

```
struct S {
    short packed_name;  // assume short represents 16-bit variable here
    int id;
};

struct S s;
char first_name = s.packed_name & 0x00ff;        // get lowest 8 bits
char last_name = (s.packed_name & 0xff00) >> 8;  // get bit 8~15, then shift it right
```

It's clear that Way A is more access efficient as these bit manipulations are not needed.

Comment: Yeah! But OP just asked about which way is efficient to store those variables.

Comment: @Lucas “Efficient” depends on your definition. If you want **space efficient**, then Way B. If you want to **time efficient**, then Way A. Sadly there is not a way both time and space efficient for your architecture.

Comment: Sure! I've another question. In case if you have any answer, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62105813/12180605)

Answer (score 0):

It is just as asking *why execution of a program written in machine language is faster than a program written in high-level language?* When you are manipulating information on bit-level execution or accessing that information is faster. So, when you store information in **Way A** it'll separately use `1 word(not 1 Byte)` for each variable(Fname, Id, Lname). But in **Way B**, what you are doing is called **data packing**. You are packing Fname and Lname in a single memory location, that's why access is faster than **Way A**.
If you know a little bit about `Structures, Slack Bytes(or padding) and Bit Fields in C`, you'll understand this easily.

Look at the given C code:--

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test
{
    char firstname;
    int id;
    char lastname;
}x;

int main()
{
    printf("Size of Struct: %d, Size of Char: %d, Size of Int: %d", sizeof(x), sizeof(char), sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Size of Struct: 12, Size of Char: 1, Size of Int: 4
```

But we all know that `sizeof a structure` is always equal to the sum of sizes of its members, i.e. here it should be `1+4+1 = 6` but because of the padding bytes between `char, int & char` in this structures, its size is 12 bytes. So, here you are accessing extra memory location than "Way B".

**Note:** Output may be different for different sequences of members or data types.

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989171/size-of-different-members-of-a-structure-in-c) for more info about `Padding Bytes` or how data is stored in memory.
Hope it helps.